# How to get all files and other custom field from document library in pnpjs sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp, pnp-js-core

I have a document library named `FileUpload`. Another folder named `FileInfoes` inside the `FileUpload`.

> FileUpload(Document Library)
>
> -----FileInfoes(Folder)
>
> -----------Name
>
> -----------Label(custom property)

How to retrieve Name & Label using PnP JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample demo to get files and mapped item.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pnp-pnpjs/1.3.5/pnpjs.es5.umd.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {            
            pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/lee/MyDoc3/ParentFolder").files.get().then(files => {
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var _ServerRelativeUrl = files[i].ServerRelativeUrl;
                    pnp.sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_ServerRelativeUrl).getItem().then(item=> {
                        console.log(item);
                    });
                }
            });
        })        
    </script>
```

[image]